# center align a string to be printed onto a file

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting

why is it such a difficult task to find a String function to center align my string when left and right align is so simple using [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) etc.

I want to format my output file

```
                                Nodes Expanded
                       Euclidean   Manhattan    Chessboard
Input1                     2           2             2
Input2                     6           6             6
Input3                     -           -             -
```

pseudocode:

```
    String line1="Nodes Expanded";
    line1.center(50);  //length of string =50
```

i can use PrintWriter to the String then.

will i have to build a logic for this or am I not aware of some inbuilt function?

Comment: Related question - [How to center a string using String.format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154366/how-to-center-a-string-using-string-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to center text:

```
public String center (String s, int length) {
    if (s.length() > length) {
        return s.substring(0, length);
    } else if (s.length() == length) {
        return s;
    } else {
        int leftPadding = (length - s.length()) / 2; 
        StringBuilder leftBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < leftPadding; i++) {
            leftBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        int rightPadding = length - s.length() - leftPadding;
        StringBuilder rightBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < rightPadding; i++) 
            rightBuilder.append(" ");

        return leftBuilder.toString() + s 
                + rightBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```