# How to center a string by formatting in Java?

Tags: java, formatting

I want my `String` to be formatted both from the left and right side, so it always keeps standing in the center.

Let's say I want the total length to be 30 symbols (let's mark spaces as stars to see clearly). I want the following result.

```
sampleString              -> *********sampleString*********
sampleLongLongString      -> *****sampleLongLongString*****
```

I tried to do the following.

```
result = padLeft("", 15) + padRight(myString, 15);
```

or

```
result = padLeft(padRight(myString, 15), 15);
```

For functions,

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);
}

public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%1$" + n + "s", s);
}
```

but no result.

Comment: Do you have to use `String.format`?

Comment: Obviously you need to take the length of your string into account.

Comment: @Pshemo not necessarily.

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah, but the final result is still unclear for me.

Comment: A `Formatter` / `String.format()` is on the one hand a bit overkill for this, and on the other hand not particularly helpful.  How about you compute the number of leading spaces required, and build up the formatted string via a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Then I would probably use http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710109/1393766

Comment: `int nPos = (s.length + n) /2;`

Comment: If you look into the answer in the above link- one thing is it needs  commons library and then if you go inside source code, it is doing everything you have to do as what you are already doing ( pad left and right)- Formatter may be right option to go.

Comment: Is it a monospaced font? If not, you may have to account for different sizes of letters

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method to add *padding* based on the length of the `String`.

Basically, you have to decide the total/max(`left+right`) padding for all the `Strings`. Please take a look at following method.

It also manages the *space* inside the `String`. Method will just return actual `String` if padding can not be added according to `maxPadding`.

```
public static String getPaddedString(String str, char paddingChar) {
    if (str == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Can not add padding in null String!");
    }

    int maxPadding = 20;//This is what you have to decide
    int length = str.length();
    int padding = (maxPadding - length) / 2;//decide left and right padding
    if (padding <= 0) {
        return str;// return actual String if padding is less than or equal to 0
    }

    String empty = "", hash = "#";//hash is used as a place holder

    // extra character in case of String with even length
    int extra = (length % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;

    String leftPadding = "%" + padding + "s";
    String rightPadding = "%" + (padding - extra) + "s";

    String strFormat = leftPadding + "%s" + rightPadding;
    String formattedString = String.format(strFormat, empty, hash, empty);

    //Replace space with * and hash with provided String
    String paddedString = formattedString.replace(' ', paddingChar).replace(hash, str);
    return paddedString;
}
```

Following program proves that above method works,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(getPaddedString("Hello", '*'));
        System.out.println(getPaddedString("Hi23", '@'));
        System.out.println(getPaddedString("Test. .Test", '%'));
        System.out.println(getPaddedString(
            "By the way, It's to long to fix !!", '*'));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
************Hello************
@@@@@@@@@@@@@Hi23@@@@@@@@@@@@
%%%%%%%%%Test. .Test%%%%%%%%%
By the way, It's to long to fix !!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy-to-understand method to do it:

```
public static String center(String string, int length, char pad) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    sb.setLength((length - string.length()) / 2);
    sb.append(string);
    sb.setLength(length);
    return sb.toString().replace('\0', pad);
}
```

With this code, when the total padding required is odd, the right-side padding has one extra pad char. To change the behaviour so that the left side gets the extra pad, change line 2 to:

```
    sb.setLength((length - string.length() + 1) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will do the trick.

```
/**
* @param int w     : length of the formatted string (e.g. 30)
* @param String s  : the string to be formatted
* @param char c    : character to pad with
* @param boolean pr: If s is odd, pad one extra left or right
* @return the original string, with pad 'p' on both sides
*/

private String pad(String s, int w, char c, boolean pr){  
   int pad = w-s.length();  
   String p = "";  

   for (int i=0; i<pad/2; i++)
      p = p + c;

   /* If s.length is odd */  
   if (pad%2 == 1)  
      /* Pad one extra either right or left */
      if (pr) s = s + c;  
      else s = c + s;  
   return (p+s+p)
}
```